# Как очистить поле вывода в NetBeans IDE?

Tags: java, netbeans

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Хотел бы очистить консоль вывода от текста, который обвел красным

---

***P.S. Может, это какая-то полезная служебная информация, но мне как новичку она пока без надобности***